# How to adjust the border colour of markers by group using plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

Using R and the plotly package. Essentially i am assigning the colour of markers by group and assigning the colour of the borders of the markers by a different group. However the problem occurs when the colour produced on the graph doesn't match the colour specified in the column.

The below code is my attempt, I was expecting the border colours of the markers to match the colours specified in the column colour in dt but this doesn't happen.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dt <- data.table(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(2,1,3,5,4),
  x2 = c(6,7,8,9,10),
  y2 = c(7,6,8,10,9),
  group = c("A","B","A","B","A"),
  group2 = c("X","Y","Z","X","Y"),
  colour = c("red","yellow","green","red","yellow")
)
  group_colours <- setNames(c("orange","purple"), c("A","B"))
  plot_ly(dt,
          x = ~x,
          y = ~y,
          type = "scatter",
          color = ~group,
          colors = ~group_colours,
          mode = "markers",
          sizes = 30,
          marker = list(size = 15,
                        line = list(color = ~colour,
                                    width = 2)),
          text = ~paste('</br> Group2:',group2,
                        '</br> Colour:', colour),
          height = 800) %>%
    add_markers(x = ~x2,
                y = ~y2,
                marker = list(size = 15,
                        line = list(color = ~colour,
                                    width = 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly error on my part, here's the solution.

```
  dt <- data.table(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
               y = c(2,1,3,5,4),
               x2 = c(6,7,8,9,10),
               y2 = c(7,6,8,10,9),
               group = c("A","B","A","B","A"),
               group2 = c("X","Y","Z","X","Y"),
               colour = c("red","yellow","green","red","yellow"
               ))[,group_colours := ifelse(group=="A","orange","purple")]



plot_ly(dt, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
    marker = list(size = 15,
                  line = list(width = 2,color = ~colour),
                  color = ~group_colours))
```